# De Rham cohomology and extension of scalars

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derham-cohomology

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $X$ be a smooth variety over $K$. Given a field extension $L/K$, I denote by $X_L$ the variety $X \times_{Spec(K)} Spec(L)$.

What is the easiest way to prove that algebraic de Rham cohomology behaves well with respect to this operation, in the following sense?
$$
H^\ast_{dR}(X) \otimes_K L \simeq H^\ast_{dR}(X_L) 
$$

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The pullback map induces a morphism not only of the algebraic de Rham cohomology, i.e., the hypercohomology of the de Rham complex, but also of the spectral sequences that compute that hypercohomology.  One of those two spectral sequences have terms that are coherent sheaves (the differentials are *not* morphisms of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules).  Thus, by flat base change, the pullback map on that page of the spectral sequence is an isomorphism.  From that stage on, the induced maps of the spectral sequence must be isomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks, Jason! Is it obvious that the isomorphisms given by flat base change commute with the differentials in the spectral sequence?

Comment: "Is it obvious that the isomorphisms given by flat base change commute with the differentials in the spectral sequence?"  This is the same question as why there are pullback maps on the de Rham complex itself, i.e., from the inverse image sheaf of the de Rham complex to the de Rham complex of the fiber product.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it. I am always very confused about what I can do with these maps which are not $\mathcal{O}_X$-linear...

Comment: Maybe one comment will help.  For a commutative diagram of schemes $f:Y_L\to X_K$ over $\text{Spec}\ L \to \text{Spec}\ K$, the pullback morphism $f^{-1}\Omega_{X_K/K}\to \Omega_{Y_L/L}$ is defined by applying the universal property to the $K$-linear derivation $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X_K} \to \mathcal{O}_{Y_L} \xrightarrow{d_{Y_L/L}} \Omega_{Y_L/L}$.  Thus, the pullback map on $\Omega$ is defined to commute with the differentials.

Comment: @JasonStarr Am I correct in thinking that your line of reasoning does not depend on characteristic zero base field? Does everything work just as well in char p or over the integers?

Comment: @SomaticCustard  Yes, the argument is not dependent on the characteristic.  You can find much more about this sort of thing in articles about the "inverse Cartier isomorphism", e.g., the following article of Torsten Wedhorn: https://www.math.nyu.edu/~tschinke/books/finite-fields/final/09_wedhorn.pdf